# Logical Operators in Workflow Designer SPD2013

Tags: 2013, workflow

I just can't figure out how to use the Logical Operations Workflow Designer in SPD2013.

I want to just write the simple statement in the workflow designer:

if field equals 'A'

and field equals 'B'
    ...
Problem is that I can't figure out how to get the AND (or OR) included.

Could you please help me on what have I missed exactly?

Comment: Which platform type are you using?

Comment: I use Sharepoint 2013 Workflow Platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess we can achieve this by using OOB conditions, but need to know when and how to use it.

**1.** Open up your workflow in edit mode, and place focus on the stage.

[image]

**2.** Select condition from the ribbon control

[image]

**3.** Use it twice in sequnce, so that it will create a logical operator.

[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: NP. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

In designer itself you can check for the logical operations

For example once you added a condition later you can select that particular and apply your logical operations using if conditions.

There are built in options available for the same in the designer ribbon.

Check this [support link](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Workflow-conditions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-d8e33ac7-9336-487f-a60b-388c4ea497ff), this link will guide you through applying different conditions in the workflow and also it will help you knowing which links are available at which step.

You can do the logical operations like :

1. Click Conditions dropdown and choose "Compare [list] field"
2. Click field and value to set those, then
3. Click Conditions dropdown again and choose "Compare [list] field"
4. Click and to change it to or, then
5. Click field and value again to set those to your second choice